# JTable color render distinguish user-added values?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have a JTable where data cells will be populated by some model, but users can overwrite these values if they deem the model-set value unsatisfactory.

I'm trying to implement a renderer with the following logic:

- If cell has no data, color background red.
- If cell has model-set data, color background white.
- If cell has user-set data, color background purple.

I've extended `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, but don't know if it's possible to distinguish "user-set" data from "model-set data".  How can swing cell renderer access the data-setting source?  The best I can think to do is to have some hidden characters to distinguish my datatypes?

I've attached a spec of how this might look.

[image]

Here is renderer code, in case helpful:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

/* 
Provides abstract methods/color defaults for JTable cell rendering.
 */
public class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


    public Color HASDATA_COLOR = Color.getHSBColor((270f/360),0.22f,0.96f);
    public Color HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = Color.getHSBColor((94f/360), 0.27f, 0.89f);


   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

      Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
               isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
      Object valueAt = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);

       // Populated cell color
       if (valueAt != null ) {
            c.setBackground(HASDATA_COLOR);
          }
       }

       if (isSelected){
          c.setBackground(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
      }      
      return c;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the renderer's code?

Comment: In your model, you need to provide a means by which you can determine if some value was changed by the use, for example, when `setValueAt` is called, the renderer would then need to ask the model if a particular cell was modified by the user and update itself based on the return value.

Comment: Yes, one sec lemme transfer it

Comment: MadProgrammer, ok thanks for clarifying.  I guess I"ll need a custom tableModel to cache these interactions.

Comment: I'd be use separate column (I"ll need a custom tableModel to cache these interactions) in XxxTableModel instead of caching (e.g. the history with details), this column should be removed from JTables view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above can work well if it is a simple one-afternoon project.

I know that it might sound a little overengineering, but I would avoid of using scalar values for that model. The problem is that one value contains, well, a value, *and* an additional status telling the source of that value, which your data model shall represent.

One "value" of your model may include a valueSource enum, telling if that is from the original, or from overridden. This simple design decision allows you further enhancing your use case (for example if you need multiple colors for multiple cases), and separates rendering from editing.

Example:

- say, you're working with currency rates. The default rates can be overridden, in some way (either by directly editing the JTable, or by using a dedicated editor dialog).
- instead of storing e.g. an array of doubles as "model", define a little better model
- first, have a class Rate (see below)
- in the renderer, when rendering a Rate, read the source type from that

```
public class Rate {
       public enum RateSource {
          EMPTY,
          DEFAULT,
          EDITED
       };

       private double rate;
       private RateSource rateSource;

       // construct an empty rate
       public Rate() {   
          this.rateSource=RateSource.EMPTY;
       }


       // construct a known rate
       public Rate(double defaultRate) {   
          this.rate=defaultRate;
          this.rateSource=RateSource.DEFAULT;
       }

       // call to set a rate, aka. edit
       public void setRate(double rate) {
          this.rate=rate;
          this.rateSource=RateSource.EDITED;
       }

       public RateSource getRateSource() {
          return rateSource;
       }
    }
}
```

(I am sorry something went wrong with the sytax highlight of this code block.)
Your data can be an array of Rate instances (but it might make sense to define a model which models the data of your application instead of using arrays which is a very over-simplified approach for modeling data for the JTable).

Then inside your renderer:

```
Rate rate = (Rate)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
switch (rate.getRateSource()) {
   case EMPTY:
        // set some color
        break;
   case EDITED:
        // set some color
        break;
   default:
        // not edited, set some color
}
```

Comment: I agree that my approach is not the best, and I like your solution. But if you only want to color a cell if it's value is different than the originally set, or you want to have a 'set to default' functionality, it's better to store the original value too I think.

Comment: I agree @Rothens. Sometimes a solution may worth of the little extra coding, but there are situations when the extra coding is a total overkill (even though it allows seamless further exensions).

In this case, I would simply store also the original value and the actual value in the Rate class, if that makes sense for the actual use case (e.g. someone wants to have an "undo edit" function). Talking about that, we can store a list of values and implement a brute force multi-level undo functionality per cell.

Comment: Another use case where my solution can be useful is when you need to render Excel-style data bars or color scales next to the values. There we can see that the color attribute of a cell has to be separated from the value of the cell.

This is a design decision, but we don't have enough info to decide if it may or may not apply to the original problem. :)

Comment: Thanks Gee Bee.  We've sort of come to this approch as well.  We'll actually store an entirely separate data layer, and the table model can be updated from it.  Furthermore, it will store all the metadata required for the renderer to derive the color.  Haven't thought it through completely yet, but it's along the lines you're proposing.  Going to accept this as the answer, since it's quite explicit and may help others who come across the question.  Rothens answer is also good, but I think this approach is probably a nice general solution

Comment: Thanks again for this answer.  Now that the project is moving along, I'm realizing this is certainly the right approach.  Thanks for having the foresight to look beyond my initial needs.

Comment: I am glad that this worked for you. OOP is a little pita when you have initially simple needs, and it is easy to lean towards simple "just works" solutions.  

However once your needs start to grow, the proper OOP solution will pay off 1001 times. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a `TableModel` extending class, which stores a 2D array of `MyData` objects which has an `initial` field, and a `data` field. The `initial` is set in the constructor, which will be your model-set value. You also set the `data` field to the `initial` there. The `MyTableModel`'s `setValueAt` function will set the model's `data` field. In your renderer, you can check if the `initial` is equals to the `data`.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks.  Let me chew on it a while and if it's satisfactory, I"ll come back and accept it.